# How to hide discord token on github

Tags: node.js, github, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot that is online 24/7. I am using Heroku to host my discord bot. Heroku gets my code uploaded to github. But, apparently github and discord are parterned and github detects when a discord token is posted on it and discord automatically changes the token. And when the token changes I can't use my bot.

Comment: I solved it but it's kinda of ghetto. Is there any like "real" ways of doing this
for example my token is "abcdefg"
const token = "bcdefg";
bot.login("a"+token);

Comment: ok I solved it by making the repository private.

Comment: You should be getting that sort of data from a separate config file- NOT hard-coded into your code.

Comment: How do I do that

Comment: @RonaldLiu https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/configuration-files.html

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in the comments, put your token in a seperat config file and dont commit the config into git (so basicly add the config file in the .gitignore file)

config.json

```
{
    "prefix": "!",
    "token": "your-token-goes-here"
}
```

.gitignore

```
config.json
```

bot.js

```
const config = require('./config.json');

...
client.login(config.token)
```

EDIT:
It is important that you do not share your token with someone else, if someone got your token and has some malicous intend they can do all kind of bad stuff with your bot. Here is a link where you read about this and why you should not give this token out at any cost.
https://github.com/reactiflux/discord-irc/wiki/Creating-a-discord-bot-&-getting-a-token

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but let's say someone wants to contribute to your bot and clone repo in their own workspace. If the config.json file is not in the repo, how are they supposed to successfully run the project without the token?

Comment: At this point they cant test it, if you thrust the persons who do want to contribute you can always give them the config.json manually. But i would't recommend this. Take a look at the part where he explains what the token is: https://github.com/reactiflux/discord-irc/wiki/Creating-a-discord-bot-&-getting-a-token
You should never give someone your bot token!

Comment: @SirPedr they should get their own token from Discord and create their own config. The project can include an *empty* template config file (often called config.example.json or similar) to help with that.